# Redirecting C++ console output to C#

Tags: c#, .net, console, process.start, console-output

I'm trying to get the output of the C++ console to the C# Windows Form application, the problem I'm having is the output of the C++ exe is displayed in the C# console only after the C++ exe is terminated. Is there anyway to get the exe output to C# console in real time while running the C++ exe (as in without having to terminate the exe)? 
Here is how I tried,

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\path\\ABC.exe";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\path\\ABC.exe";
p.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Ah, my answer was exactly the same but I was too slow.

Comment: Thanks Max, it works fine with OutputDataReceived. Yet performance is quite slow when getting the output to c# console, but that's ok i guess.

Answer (score 0):

See [Console.SetIn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setin.aspx) (and SetOut) and [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)